# help to understand have/have been example

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

what is the difference between these examples and which one is correct.

1) I have this phone for years 
2) I have been this phone for years

Comment: I have had this phone for years.

Comment: what is past particle in this sentence,

Comment: In my post how these sentences are wrong

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use the verb *to have* as a main verb. Your second sentence has the verb *to be* as a main verb. So the second sentence isn't correct.As for the first sentence, though the verb (to have) is a correct choice, the tense is incorrect. When you say **for years**, it means you started using this thing long ago and are still enjoying it. In this case we use present perfect.

> I have had this phone for years.

Comment: Yes, but it's worth pointing out that it's not difficult to contrive a context in which the tense *is* valid in the first example. *I never really liked having to get used to a different device every time I started another 12 month contract. But now I've bought my own phone, which I use on a pay-as-you-go basis. It's reassuring to know that unless I break or lose it, **I have this phone for years**.*